# How to add an admin page for a custom module in Socialengine 4

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

How can we create an administration panel page for a custom module in social engine 4? I have not found any information regarding this over the INTERNET.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method or functionality to create "administration panel page for a custom module". You need to do the programming (define Admin-controller and corresponding action) in your custom module.

You can take the reference from path: "application/modules/User/controllers/AdminManageController.php/indexAction()" and corresponding view file at "application/modules/User/views/scripts/admin-manage/index.tpl". This action display the "Manage Users" page at admin panel. You can do the programming according to your requirements.

Please put the moduleName, controllerName and actionName according to your requirement in below query and this will show in "Admin panel" >> "Plugins" section.

INSERT IGNORE INTO `engine4_core_menuitems` (`name`, `module`, `label`, `plugin`, `params`, `menu`, `submenu`, `order`) VALUES
('core_admin_main_plugins_moduleName', 'moduleName', 'moduleName', '', '{"route":"admin_default","module":"moduleName","controller":"controllerName", "action":"actionName"}', 'core_admin_main_plugins', '', 999);

Comment: I have created a module but unable to show in admin panel. Right now its fine working on the link "admin/module_name/setting". i just want that a menu. when user click on that it will redirect to module "admin/module_name/setting"

Comment: Please put the moduleName, controllerName and actionName according to your requirement in below query and this will show in "Admin panel" >> "Plugins" section.

INSERT IGNORE INTO `engine4_core_menuitems` (`name`, `module`, `label`, `plugin`, `params`, `menu`, `submenu`, `order`) VALUES
('core_admin_main_plugins_moduleName', 'moduleName', 'moduleName', '', '{"route":"admin_default","module":"moduleName","controller":"controllerName", "action":"actionName"}', 'core_admin_main_plugins', '', 999);